# Android network connectivity states missing.

Tags: java, android, wifi, state, connectivity

I'm trying to assess my phones ability to connect to my wifi network. I want to figure out how long it takes to authenticate to my wifi access point, how long it is taking to obtain an IP address, etc..

I've made a lot of progress thanks to this website and lots of testing. However I can never seam to be able to get my broadcast receiver to trigger off certain connection states. I would really like to get somehow detect the time when authentication occurs.

Now I know what the Android documentation says and the Authentication state should be an easy thing to access. However in practice with multiple devices, that state is never reached. I've even tried polling with the following code.

```
    public void start(long delayMillsec) {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {



                @Override
                public void run() {
                    long timeout = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;
                    running = true;
                    while(true)
                    {
                    int oldState = state;
                    showWifiStatus();
                    int newState = state;
                    if(newState != oldState)
                    {
                        Log.e("STATE", stateString + ": " + System.nanoTime());
                    }

                    }
                } }
        , delayInMillsec);
}

    public void showWifiStatus() {
        boolean connected = false;
        boolean associated = false;


        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) thisContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);


 DetailedState val =  mWifi.getDetailedState();

        if (val == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.SCANNING) {
            //Log.e("Detailed Wifi Info","     wifi state is SCANNING "); 
            state = 0;
            stateString = "SCANNING";
        }
        if (val == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CONNECTING) {
            //Log.e("Detailed Wifi Info","     wifi state is CONNECTING  ");
            associated = true;
            state = 1;
            stateString = "CONNECTING";
    }
        if (val == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.AUTHENTICATING) {
                //Log.e("Detailed Wifi Info","    3wifi state is AUTHENTICATING");
                associated = true;
                state = 2;
                stateString = "AUTHENTICATING";
        }
        if (val == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.OBTAINING_IPADDR) {
            //Log.e("Detailed Wifi Info","     wifi state is OBTAINING_IPADDR");
            associated = true;
            state = 3;
            stateString = "OBTAINING_IPADDR";
    }


        if (val == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CONNECTED) {
            //Log.e("Detailed Wifi Info","     wifi state is CONNECTED ");
            connected = true;
            associated = true;
            state = 4;
            stateString = "CONNECTED";
    }
        if (val == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.DISCONNECTED) {
                //Log.e("Detailed Wifi Info","     wifi state is DISCONNECTED   "); 
                state = 5;
                stateString = "DISCONNECTED";
        }
        if (val == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.DISCONNECTING) {
               // Log.e("Detailed Wifi Info","     wifi state is DISCONNECTING   "); 
                state = 6;
                stateString = "DISCONNECTING";
        }
        if (val == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.FAILED) {
                //Log.e("Detailed Wifi Info","     wifi state is FAILED"); 
                state = 7;
                stateString = "FAILED";
        }
        if (val == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.IDLE) {
                //Log.e("Detailed Wifi Info","     wifi state is IDLE"); 
                state = 8;
                stateString = "IDLE";
        }

        if (val == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.SUSPENDED) {
                //Log.e("Detailed Wifi Info","     wifi state is SUSPENDED"); 
                state = 9;
                stateString = "SUSPENDED";
        }
}
```

Where I call the start function immediately from a background service, then I walked around between known wifi AP's and disconnected the wifi and reconnected etc...

I've also tried the connectivity receiver to pick up whatever I could.

I used this intent filter:

```
IntentFilter ConnectedFilter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
ConnectedFilter.addAction(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION); 
ConnectedFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);
ConnectedFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);

    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(ConnectedToAPReceiver,
            ConnectedFilter);
```

With this receiver, to output absolutely EVERYTHING that was being received. And there was never any indication that the authentication state is ever triggered.

```
    private BroadcastReceiver ConnectedToAPReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String action = intent.getAction();
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            if (extras != null) {
                Log.e("NEW Action", intent.getAction());
                for (String key: extras.keySet()) {
                   Log.e("CONN_ACTION", "key [" + key + "]: " +
                      extras.get(key));
                }
                Log.e("NEW THING", "------------");
             }
             else {
                Log.e("CONNACTION", "no extras");
             }
}};
```

I'm using the following permissions too:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Are there any Android experts out there who can help me on this one? Ideally I would like to get some working code that I can use, but even some good information on why this state never does get reached would be very helpful. Is this a bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me:

```
IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
registerReceiver(receiverWifi, mIntentFilter);


class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        String action  = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)){
            Log.d("WifiReceiver", ">>>>SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION<<<<<<");
            SupplicantState supl_state=((SupplicantState)intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NEW_STATE));
            switch(supl_state){
            case ASSOCIATED:Log.i("SupplicantState", "ASSOCIATED");
                break;
            case ASSOCIATING:Log.i("SupplicantState", "ASSOCIATING");
                break;
            case AUTHENTICATING:Log.i("SupplicantState", "Authenticating...");
                break;
            case COMPLETED:Log.i("SupplicantState", "Connected");
                break;
            case DISCONNECTED:Log.i("SupplicantState", "Disconnected");
                break;
            case DORMANT:Log.i("SupplicantState", "DORMANT");
                break;
            case FOUR_WAY_HANDSHAKE:Log.i("SupplicantState", "FOUR_WAY_HANDSHAKE");
                break;
            case GROUP_HANDSHAKE:Log.i("SupplicantState", "GROUP_HANDSHAKE");
                break;
            case INACTIVE:Log.i("SupplicantState", "INACTIVE");
                break;
            case INTERFACE_DISABLED:Log.i("SupplicantState", "INTERFACE_DISABLED");
                break;
            case INVALID:Log.i("SupplicantState", "INVALID");
                break;
            case SCANNING:Log.i("SupplicantState", "SCANNING");
                break;
            case UNINITIALIZED:Log.i("SupplicantState", "UNINITIALIZED");
                break;
            default:Log.i("SupplicantState", "Unknown");
                break;

            }
            int supl_error=intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_ERROR, -1);
            if(supl_error==WifiManager.ERROR_AUTHENTICATING){
                Log.i("ERROR_AUTHENTICATING", "ERROR_AUTHENTICATING!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            }
        }
    }
}

<receiver
    android:name=".MyActivity$WifiReceiver"
    android:process=":remote" >
</receiver>
```

Comment: I was missing this: mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);

Thanks!